# Compare and Get Some values Array of Object on Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Can this variable data match the output? I tried combining it, but it didn't work, it only produced 1 line, which didn't match the outcome. I tried using sort, but I still don't know how to display two sides of an array-like that.

```
//Output Associative-Array
[
["row3", "row5"],

["row1", "row2"],

["row4", ""],

["", "row6"],

["row7", "row8"]
]
```

This is my code

```
   const arr = [
    {id: 2, value: 'row1', position: 'S'},
    {id: 2, value: 'row2', position: 'A'},
    {id: 1, value: 'row3', position: 'S'},
    {id: 3, value: 'row4', position: 'S'},
    {id: 1, value: 'row5', position: 'A'},
    {id: 4, value: 'row6', position: 'A'},
    {id: 5, value: 'row7', position: 'S'},
    {id: 5, value: 'row8', position: 'A'}
  ]
```

Comment: What's the question here? If you're having trouble getting your code to work, you need to post the failing code and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: Please show text data as text, not as a link to a picture of text. You can use [Markdown tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356997/194720).

Comment: I've edited it, it helps me tidy it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following using array reduce method,

```js
arr = [
    {id: 2, value: 'row1', position: 'S'},
    {id: 2, value: 'row2', position: 'A'},
    {id: 1, value: 'row3', position: 'S'},
    {id: 3, value: 'row4', position: 'S'},
    {id: 1, value: 'row5', position: 'A'},
    {id: 4, value: 'row6', position: 'A'},
    {id: 5, value: 'row7', position: 'S'},
    {id: 5, value: 'row8', position: 'A'}
  ]

arr.sort((a,b) => a.id - b.id);

ret = arr.reduce((prev, curr) => {
  if(!prev[curr.id - 1]) {
    prev[curr.id - 1] = ['', ''];
    
  }
  
  if(curr.position === 'A') {
      prev[curr.id - 1][1] = curr.value;
    } else {
      prev[curr.id - 1][0] = curr.value;
    }
 
  return prev;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(ret));
```

Comment: This adds to my insight regarding reduce method.
Thank you, I really appreciate it.